# Remove 0 from output

Tags: c

I want to end the program when a user inputs "0" which is working fine when I am using the do/while loop but now I don't want the "0" to appear on the output... I just want the program to end when the user inputs 0 but not count it as the output line

This is my input: (per line)

```
1.0
0.2
10.0
20.0
0
```

Here is the main part of my code:

```
main()
{
    float* fArray;
    float value;
    int counter = 0;
    int i;

    do
    {
        scanf("%f", &value);
        *(fArray + counter) = value;
        counter++;
    }
    while (value != 0);

    printf("\nThe original values are: ");
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        printf("%g ", *(fArray + i));
}
```

Comment: I hope you allocate space for your pointer somewhere?... `malloc` anyone? And just do `counter--` after you finished reading in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do
{
    scanf("%f", &value);

    if (value != 0)
    {
        *(fArray + counter) = value;
        counter++;
    }
}
while (value != 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things you ought to always do right: I edited and annotated your code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // for I/O
#include <stdlib.h>  // for malloc

//main()         
int main(void) { // get the signature of main() right
    float* fArray;
    float value = -1;
    int N_MAX=100;  // decide on largest number of entries you will allow
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    // allocate memory for the array!
    if((fArray = malloc(N_MAX * sizeof *fArray))==NULL) { // <<< and check that it worked
      fprintf(stderr, "error allocating memory\n");
      return -1;
    }

    do
    {
        // scan, and test for valid input:
        if(0 == scanf("%f", &value)) break;  // test that a float was read
        if (value==0) {
          break; // 0 = "end of input"
        }
        *(fArray + counter++) = value; // we only increment counter if valid value read
        if(counter >= N_MAX) {   // <<< don't run past the end of the array
          fprintf(stderr, "maximum number of entries reached\n");
          break;
        }
    }
    while (1==1);  // "infinite" loop - we break internally when break condition is met 

    // taking the next line out: moving some of the functionality into the loop
    // to correct the logic as pointed out in the comments
    // counter--; // undo the "one too far" count

    printf("\ntotal number of good values: %d\n", counter);
    printf("The original values are: ");
    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) { // <<<< good habit to use {} even for a one liner
        printf("%g ", *(fArray + i));
    }
    printf("\n"); // <<< don't want to end without CRLF - or prompt will be at end of line
}
```

Comment: Careful. The `counter--` will erase an entry, or even end up with `counter == -1`, if the user types an invalid number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate some memory to place the values.

I.e.

```
float fArray[1000]; // Some large enough number here
```

Then use

```
scanf("%f", &value)); // Hopefully you get the picture and also you should check the return value
fArray[counter++] = value;
```

This will also increase the index `counter`

Comment: @Floris - Typo I am afraid

Comment: You make it hard to test for zero with your code. By the time you can test `counter` is pointing to the next element.

Comment: @Floris - You are right - Corrected. I also think that `scanf` return value needs to be checked as well

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < counter-1; i++)
        printf("%g ", *(fArray + i));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you may use if statement to not print "0" in output statement, like

```
for(i=0;i<counter;i++)

{if(*(fArray + i)==0)
  {}
 else{
   printf("%g ", *(fArray + i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main() {

float* fArray;
float value;
int counter = 0;
int i;
fArray = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*100); 

while(1){
    scanf("%f", &value);
    if(value == 0) {
          break;
    }
    *(fArray + counter ) = value;
    counter++; 
}

printf("\nThe original values are: ");
for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    printf("%g ", *(fArray + i));
}
```